# Pause..... option like the default camera app?

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, video-recording

I've been trying to look for a better solution to pause and resume the video recording.
As far as I know, Media Recorder class does not allow to pause during the recording for Android 4.3 or below.

I found the mp4parser library that can merge several video files into one video file.
I am using the following jars:

**aspectjrt-1.7.3.jar**

**isoparser-1.0.6.jar**

The problem is it takes way too long to merge them together.
For example,
2-3 video files which are around 5 mins long total would take at least 2 mins to merge them!!

The default Camera app that comes with my Galaxy S3 and Note 2 which have the pause option on the video recording.
Their paused videos take less than 1 second to complete the merging.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

I am using the code below to merge the video files:

```
for (ArrayList<String> PathList : VideoList) {
            VideoPathList = PathList;
        }

        for (String mMovie : VideoPathList) {
            Movie movie = MovieCreator.build(mMovie);
            MovieList.add(movie);
        }

        List<Track> videoTracks = new LinkedList<Track>();
        List<Track> audioTracks = new LinkedList<Track>();
        for (Movie mMovie : MovieList) {
            for (Track t : mMovie.getTracks()) {
                if (t.getHandler().equals("soun")) {
                    audioTracks.add(t);
                }
                if (t.getHandler().equals("vide")) {
                    videoTracks.add(t);
                }
            }
        }

          Movie result = new Movie();

          if(audioTracks.size() > 0) {
             result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(audioTracks.toArray(new Track[audioTracks.size()])));
          }
          if(videoTracks.size() > 0) {
             result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(videoTracks.toArray(new Track[videoTracks.size()])));
          }

          BasicContainer basicContainer = (BasicContainer) new DefaultMp4Builder().build(result);

          final String FileLocation = (UserSavedDirectoryPATH + "/");
          final File DirectoryExistCheck = new File(FileLocation);
          if(!DirectoryExistCheck.exists()) {
              DirectoryExistCheck.mkdir();
          }
          NewVideo = FileLocation + "Video " + ".mp4"; 

          FileChannel fileChannel = new FileOutputStream(new File(String.format(NewVideo))).getChannel();
          basicContainer.writeContainer(fileChannel);
          fileChannel.close();
        } catch(Exception error) {  }
        GalleryAddNewVideo(NewVideo);   
        Delete_VideoPaths(VideoPathList);
```

I very appreciate for your help,

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps doing the recording in raw may increase the performance:

1. Save the recording to a raw file (instead of in an encoded format).
2. Append to the end of the same raw file every time user resumes recording.
3. Finally, on stop, convert the raw file to desired format (mp4 or whatever)

This way, you wouldn't need mp4parser or anything else to merge the videos.

Comment: Thanks alot for the comment.  Is there anyway you can share some code or sample or link?  Thank you very much